# CodeIgniter and query string issue

Tags: codeigniter, search, routes

Im not to good in php and codeigniter gives me maximum. My site is a search engine and after i do a search, url of my site is like this: **mysite.com/?search=eminem&type=mp3** and i don't like it.
I want to do it so when i type search eminem to give me this url: **mysite.com/eminem/mp3**
Here is code from CI

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

what other code do i have to add here to transform the qwery strings to paths?

here is routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';

$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Here is my search form from home.php

```
<form id="searchwrapper" name="searchform">                                          <input type="text" class="searchbox" id="txtSearch" name="search" />                                        <input type="image" src="../images/empty.png" class="searchbox_submit"/>                                   

<p id="circ">
   <input  type="radio" id="mp3" name="type" checked value="mp3"/>
   <label class="circ-btn normal" for="mp3">Mp3</label></p>
<p id="circ">                   
   <input type="radio" id="album" name="type" <?php echo $radio2;?> value="album"/>
   <label class="circ-btn normal" for="album">Album</label></p>
</form>
```

here is .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /ci/
        #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        #request to index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is $config['uri_protocol'] set to in your config file?

Comment: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Comment: Can you post the contents of your .htaccess file and double check to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: i updated my question with the .htaccess /ci/ is where actualy my site is located. And yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mod_rewrite is already working, then you can set this in your routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "pages/search/$1/$2";
```

I'm differentiating `pages/search` from `pages/view` so it would be less confusing.
By the way, this has to be the last route in your routes.php file so it has low priority and won't conflict with specific routes like the samples below. Because if it's on top of your routes file, then accessing `users/list` will be treated as `search=users&type=list`.

```
$route['users/list'] = "users/list";
$route['pages/list'] = "pages/list";
```

Then in your pages controller.

```
public function search($search = '', $type = '')
{
   // $search now contains $1 and $type contains $2
   // instead of $_GET['search'] and $_GET['type']
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: do i have to write something in public function search($search = '', $type = '') because is not working

Comment: Hi there, how do you present the search results? You just use the same code. I'm assuming you already have the search feature. You just want to beautify your url.